# Ranger rest api to get all users in a group

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-ranger

I have a requirement to get all users currently in a group (internal) through API , but using Group rest API , I am not able to get the users in it.

```
curl -s -u admin:pass -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://ranger.com/service/xusers/groups/14080
```

Output:

```
    {
  "id": 14080,
  "createDate": "2019-11-18T18:17:55Z",
  "updateDate": "2020-01-13T22:19:33Z",
  "owner": "Admin",
  "updatedBy": "Admin",
  "name": "test_group",
  "description": "for internal users",
  "groupType": 0,
  "groupSource": 0,
  "isVisible": 1
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ranger UserSync only sync user and groups from operational system (redhat, centos, etc...) and ldap bases (IDM, MS-AD, ...). If you want to get users inside groups, you will need to search directly from source:

Locally from OS:

```
cat /etc/group | grep <group>
```

Or remotely in LDAP/MS-AD with ldapsearch (maybe you need to install first):

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<server> -b "OU=Organizational_Unit,DC=domain,DC=name,DC=com" -x -v -D user@domain.name.com -w password '(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=group))'
```